# Send dns queryis over ssl

Tags: linux, ssl, dns, resolve

I need to dns over ssl. DNS queryis UDP packeted and I need to change it to SSL protocol?

It is working in linux.

How does ubuntu 12.04 resolves dns and how to change to SSL?

I have tried create ssl socket and send dns queryis.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <openssl/rsa.h> 
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
//#include "server.h"
#define FAIL    -1

void initChild(int cli, SSL_CTX* ctx);

void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int count, char *strings[]) {
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    char *portnum;
    SSL*     ssl;
    int cli;
    struct hostent *hp;
    int pid;
    if (count != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    SSL_library_init();
    portnum = strings[1];
    ctx = InitServerCTX();
    LoadCertificates(ctx, "ser-cert.pem", "ser-key.pem");
    server = OpenListener(atoi(portnum));
    while (1) {
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        int len = sizeof(addr);
        int cli = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);

        if (!(pid = fork())) {
            //Child process
            //close(server);
            initChild(cli, ctx);
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (pid > 0) {
            //Parent process
        }
        else {
            printf("Fork failed!!");
            //close(server);
        }
    }
    close(server);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 0;
}

void initChild(int cli, SSL_CTX* ctx) {
    SSL*     ssl;
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, cli);
    DnsData(ssl);
}
```

This works in terminal mode. Now I need to change terminal mode to GUI mode. GUI mode is web browser. This code uses ssl certificate generated by me. How to write simple ssl dns queried web browser in c?